# Footer should cover the rest of the height

Tags: css

i have a blackout at the moment.

I have a wrapper class which is at the top of the page and i want that the footer covers the rest of the page. But at the moment, the footer has height:100%; and creates a scrollbar.

I just want that the footer fills up the rest of the height of the body minus the height of the wrapper, but with no scrollbar. How can i solve this?

Example:
http://codepen.io/anon/pen/yDhLK

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the footer inside the closing `</div>` tag for the wrapper.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/imgBt